# CSS - making symbol stay always on second line

Tags: html, css

I want to that symbol **->** (text element) would only appear in second line. For example if text would be one line

```
John
->
```

and if there would be two lines of text symbol would still be on second line.

```
John and 
Tom ->
```

is it possible? 
Currently how it is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="inner-box">
     <span class="inner-box-text">Category<i class="icon-font icon-long-arrow"></i></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inner-box {
  bottom: 16%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 25%;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 51px;
}
.inner-box span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  line-height: 25px;
  max-width: 270px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.inner-box i {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all the span should be closed as well like so:

```
<div class="inner-box">
     <span class="inner-box-text">Category<i class="icon-font icon-long-arrow"></i></span>
</div>
```

What you are likely looking for is CSS selector `:after`

```
<style>
    .inner-box-text:after { 
        content: " --- whatever should come after";
    }
</style>
```

Sadly the `:after` selector does not support HTML, only text.

Another possibility would be the use of jQuery to append something.

Alex

Comment: Thanks for correction. Sadly even though I would be able to type "->" as a text problem would still remain as it would keep inline with first line.

Comment: Well ok, just do
`<span class="inner-box-text">Category and so on<br>more and so one<br class="last_br"></span>` and apply the :after to .last_br

Comment: Sorry my mistake....
`<span class="inner-box-text" >My text<br>gagaga<br><span class="last_line"></span></span>` and apply the :after to .last_line
`.last_line:after { 
        content: "dsdsdsd";
    }`

Comment: For second line it would jump to a third line which is not okay.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below `code`

```
<div class="inner-box">
     <span class="inner-box-text">Category</span><i class="icon-font icon-long-arrow"></i>
</div>
```

and below css

```
.vip-inner-box {
    bottom: 16%;
    left: 10%;
    right: 25%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 51px;
    span {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      font: $font-weight-light 24px $font-custom;
      color: white;
      line-height: 25px;
      max-width: 270px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
  }
    i {
      padding-top: 5px;
        display:block; 
    }
```

Comment: Symbol would always be shown as a seperate line which is not a case here. It should show with a second line text in a second line and break only for first line (for one line text).

Comment: i don't think it is possible by using only CSS, may be it is possible if you are using some coding language (c#, vb etc) but there also you can count characters not the lines. I hope you understand i am trying to say.